# Output JRuby heap space from application code

Tags: jruby

Is there a way of outputting the Java heap space, the JRuby application was started with (like `-J-Xms2048m`), from the application code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed in at the JVM command line is available in the Runtime JMX bean provided by the JDK, as @stephanlindauer pointed out.

Another way that's less sensitive to how the JVM was launched is to use the Memory bean, like so:

```
membean = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.memory_mx_bean
heap = membean.heap_memory_usage
puts heap.max
```

On my system with no special JRuby flags, this outputs "466092032" (roughly reflecting our default max of 500MB), and when specifying a 2GB maximum heap, (`jruby -J-Xmx2g`) it outputs "1908932608".

Answer (score 0):

turns out, you can puts values that were passed in via the environment variables like this:

`puts java.lang.System.getenv()['JRUBY_OPTS']`

or

`puts ENV['JRUBY_OPTS']`

or

`puts java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().to_s`

remember to `require "java"` before.